# Is it safe to keep .dpkg-old files in /etc/grub.d?

Tags: grub2, 22.04, dpkg

A release upgrade asked me whether I would like to use the new or old version of `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` file. I chose the new one, but noticed now that the old (slightly manually patched) file is still there, named `10_linux.dpkg-old`.

My understanding is that `update-grub` will run all the scripts in `/etc/grub.d`. Since there have been a few bugs fixed in the new version of the `10_linux` script, I do not want `update-grub` to run `10_linux.dpkg-old`.

I assume making the old script non-executable using `chmod` would allow me to keep it in that folder. But I would like to know whether there is some other mechanism preventing `update-grub` from using it.

Reference of my current understanding: [help.ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup)

> The scripts in this directory are read during execution of the update-grub command and their instructions are incorporated into /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
>
> The placement of the menu items in the grub.cfg menu is determined by
> the order in which the files in this directory are run. Files with a
> leading numeral are executed first, beginning with the lowest number.
> 10_linux is run before 20_memtest, which would run before 40_custom.
> If files with alphabetic names exist, they are run after the
> numerically-named files.
>
> Custom menu entries can be added to the 40_custom file or in a newly
> created file. Based on its name, 40_custom entries by default appear
> at the bottom of the menu. A custom file beginning with 06_ would
> appear at the top of the menu since its alphanumeric sorting would
> place it ahead of 10_ through 40_ files.
>
> Only executable files generate output to grub.cfg during execution of
> update-grub. By default the files in the /etc/grub.d folder are
> executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it safe to keep .dpkg-old files in /etc/grub.d?

Yes.

The `grub-mkconfig` script will ignore filenames that match [`*~` or `*/\#*\#`](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-core-dev/grub/+git/ubuntu/tree/util/grub-mkconfig.in?id=13ce705d48dde830beda15d9a656f0677a26f620#n275), and filenames that match [`*.dpkg-*`, or `*.rpmsave|*.rpmnew`, or `README*|*/README*`, or `*.sig`](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-core-dev/grub/+git/ubuntu/tree/util/grub-mkconfig_lib.in?id=13ce705d48dde830beda15d9a656f0677a26f620#n188).

You can trace the script if you want to confirm this with the command `bash -x $(which grub-mkconfig) -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Comment: oh, looking at the source - smart! I forgot that was an option